# Getting a " undefined local variable or method " error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typhoeus

I run a command:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test    
ruby service.rb -p 3000 -e test
```

And I get this error:

```
, [2013-01-31T10:25:22.197106 #999] DEBUG -- : env: test
service.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `databases' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I am very new to Rails, can someone brainstorm on what are the things I should be looking at to find the issue? This is from a Tutorial on creating a client app for a Sinatra Rail service with Typheous

**EDIT**: Here is the link to the service.rb sourcefile that is giving error
https://github.com/babakinks/HisFirstService/blob/master/service.rb

Comment: Please post your code, and be sure to clearly identify which is line 16.

Comment: will do. Just a minute I put on github somewhere...

Comment: @jdl : Ok here is the link to Service.rb code: https://github.com/babakinks/HisFirstService/blob/master/service.rb

Comment: you should be looking at where databases is defined. you start referencing it on line 16, but it is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like Javid mentioned in the comment I was missing the line to define what is the variable "databases"

Added this:

```
databases = YAML.load_file("config/database.yml")
```

Still have some more errors now but as far as this question, that's what was missing.